# Devise Invitable - Redirect to role based dashboard if access denied sending invitation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

Hey all I have a simple app.. It has a few roles.. but right now not sure which authorization library I'm going to use..

So as it sits, i have it set so only and administrator or dispatcher can send a new user invite to the system..

if a user with a role other than those permitted tries to access the invitations page it redirects to the root_path, however I want them to be redirected back to their respective dashboard.

I have done something similar on login as seen below.

I am trying to achieve something similar for the `authenticate_inviter!` method.

any suggestions? I cant seem to think of a good way to get this done.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if current_user.role == "admin"
    dashboard_admin_user_path
  elsif current_user.role == "dispatch"
    dashboard_dispatch_user_path
  elsif current_user.role == "owner"
    dashboard_owner_user_path
  elsif current_user.role == "driver"
    dashboard_driver_user_path
  elsif current_user.role == "client"
    dashboard_client_user_path
  elsif current_user.role == "guest"
    dashboard_guest_user_path
  else
    root_path
  end
end



protected

  def authenticate_inviter!
    unless current_user.role=='admin' && unless current_user.role == 'dispatch'
      redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Access Denied, only Administrators can invite new users"
    end
    super
  end

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation, keys: [:f_name, :l_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation])
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:invite, keys: [:f_name, :l_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation])
end

end
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

after playing with it I came up with this solution:

```
  def authenticate_inviter!
    unless current_user.role=='admin' or current_user.role == 'dispatch'
  if current_user.role == "owner"
    redirect_to dashboard_owner_user_path, :alert => "Access Denied, only Administrators or Dispatchers can invite new users"
  elsif current_user.role == "driver"
    redirect_to dashboard_driver_user_path, :alert => "Access Denied, only Administrators or Dispatchers can invite new users"
  elsif current_user.role == "client"
    redirect_to dashboard_client_user_path, :alert => "Access Denied, only Administrators or Dispatchers can invite new users"
  elsif current_user.role == "guest"
    redirect_to dashboard_guest_user_path, :alert => "Access Denied, only Administrators or Dispatchers can invite new users"
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end
    end
    super
  end
```